# MoPub security vulnerability

Tags: android, mopub, android-security

For a while now I've had a warning on my developer console regarding a MoPub security vulnerability. It comes from my mediation ad network (Appodeal). However, I have long since receiving this warning removed ALL ads from the application and resubmitted quite a few new apk versions, but the warning persists.

When I say i've removed all ads, I mean all external libraries (including MoPub), all code & anything declared in the manifest. I can't figure out what is lingering in the app that is triggering off this warning. Usually after posting an update the warning will go away for a few hours after submission, and then return. It's doing my head in.

What, precisely, do I need to do to stop this warning message? Thanks in advance.

Here is a Google Help link explaining the issue: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6345928

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't remove Mopub, you just need to update Appodeal sdk.
You can find the link to the new sdk version here (native android): http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1&platform=1#p_2

And also you can write to Appodeal support chat about any technical questions :)